# Python error when handling multiprocessing with Pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've built a model that provides an optimal missile-target interception trajectory for a given input of state parameters. I want to generate several interception trajectories by iterating through a list of input state parameters and I'm trying to use multiprocessing to do so. The following function defines the code that performs the optimization and stores the output variables in an excel sheet. The `Counter` variable ensures that for every list of input states, a new Excel file is saved.

```
import openmdao.api as om
import numpy as np
import dymos as dm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from MIssileODEdef import MissileODE
import pandas as pd


def CompOptimalTraj(States):

    #decompose states array into individual states

    X_m=States[0] 
    Y_m=States[1] 
    X_t=States[2] 
    Y_t=States[3] 
    theta=States[4] 
    phi_t =States[5] 
    phi_m=States[6] 
    V_m=States[7] 
    V_t=States[8] 
    A_t=States[9] 
    Counter = States[10]
    
    # Initialize problem and solution driver

    p = om.Problem(model=om.Group())

    p.driver = om.pyOptSparseDriver()


    p.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'IPOPT'
    p.driver.declare_coloring()


    # Initialize a single phase solution trajectory

    traj = p.model.add_subsystem('traj', dm.Trajectory())

    phase = traj.add_phase('phase0', dm.Phase(
        ode_class=MissileODE, transcription=dm.GaussLobatto(num_segments=25, order=3)))

    phase.set_time_options(fix_initial=True, duration_bounds=(.5, 40))

    phase.add_state('X_m', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False,
                    rate_source='Xm_dot', units='m', lower=0, upper=10000)

    phase.add_state('Y_m', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False,
                    rate_source='Ym_dot', units='m', lower=0, upper=10000)

    phase.add_state('X_t', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False,
                    rate_source='Xt_dot', units='m', lower=0, upper=10000)

    phase.add_state('Y_t', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False,
                    rate_source='Yt_dot', units='m', lower=0, upper=10000)

    phase.add_state('theta', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False, lower=0,
                    upper=np.pi, rate_source='theta_dot', units='rad', targets=['theta'])

    phase.add_state('phi_t', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False, lower=0,
                    upper=np.pi, rate_source='phi_tdot', units='rad', targets=['phi_t'])

    phase.add_state('phi_m', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False, lower=0,
                    upper=np.pi, rate_source='phi_mdot', units='rad', targets=['phi_m'])

    phase.add_state('V_m', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False, lower=300,
                    upper=1200, rate_source='A_m', units='m/s', targets=['V_m'])

    phase.add_state('V_t', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False, lower=-
                    600, upper=-300, rate_source='A_t', units='m/s', targets=['V_t'])

    phase.add_control('A_m', continuity=True, rate_continuity=True,
                    units='m/(s**2)', lower=-50, upper=50, targets=['A_m'])

    phase.add_parameter('A_t', val=A_t, units='m/s**2',
                        opt=False, targets=['A_t'])

    phase.add_boundary_constraint(
        'R =((X_t - X_m)**2 + (Y_t - Y_m)**2)**0.5', loc='final', equals=1)

    phase.add_objective('time', loc='final')
    #phase.add_objective('time', loc='final')

    p.model.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver()

    p.setup()


    # Set the initial values
    
    p['traj.phase0.t_initial'] = 0.0
    p['traj.phase0.t_duration'] = 40

    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:X_m', phase.interp('X_m', ys=[X_m, 0.5]))
    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:Y_m', phase.interp('Y_m', ys=[Y_m, 1]))
    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:X_t', phase.interp('X_t', ys=[X_t, 1]))
    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:Y_t', phase.interp('Y_t', ys=[Y_t, 0.2]))
    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:theta',
            phase.interp('theta', ys=[theta, np.pi]))
    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:V_t', phase.interp('V_t', ys=[V_t, -300]))
    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:phi_t',
            phase.interp('phi_t', ys=[phi_t, np.pi]))
    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:phi_m', phase.interp(
        'phi_m', ys=[phi_m,  np.pi]))
    p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:V_m', phase.interp('V_m', ys=[V_m, 1200]))


    p.set_val('traj.phase0.controls:A_m', phase.interp('A_m', [0, 0]))

    dm.run_problem(p, run_driver=True, simulate = True, solution_record_file='dymos_solution'+str(Counter)+'.db',simulation_record_file='dymos_simulation'+str(Counter)+'.db')
    #p.record("after_run_driver")

    exp_out = traj.simulate()

    sol = om.CaseReader('dymos_solution'+str(Counter)+'.db').get_case('final')
    sim = om.CaseReader('dymos_simulation'+str(Counter)+'.db').get_case('final')

    t = sol.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.time')
    X_m = sol.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.states:X_m')
    Y_m = sol.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.states:Y_m')
    X_t = sol.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.states:X_t')
    Y_t = sol.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.states:Y_t')

    A_m = sol.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.controls:A_m')

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(t,X_m,Y_m,X_t,Y_t,A_m)))
    
    return df.to_excel('MissileStateHistory'+str(Counter)+'.xlsx')
```

The following is my multiprocessing code. `StateParams` is a list of arrays corresponding to the input state parameters.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from MissileOPT import CompOptimalTraj
from multiprocessing import Pool
  
xl = pd.read_excel('Trial5StateParamGen.xlsx')
StateParams = xl.to_numpy()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
       pool.map(CompOptimalTraj,StateParams)
```

When I run this code, I can see two of my CPU cores reaching 100% utilization and eventually one excel file is saved and I get the following exception. I'm not quite sure what this means or how to handle it. Any ideas?

Here's the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "c:\Users\Name\OneDrive - University of Bath\Desktop\Uni stuff\5th year uni\FYP\Code\OC\OC_algos_Trial5-Multiprocessing\MissileOPT.py", line 112, in CompOptimalTraj
    dm.run_problem(p, run_driver=True, simulate=True)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dymos\run_problem.py", line 79, in run_problem
    problem.final_setup()
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\utils\hooks.py", line 131, in execute_hooks
    ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\problem.py", line 1030, in final_setup
    self._setup_recording()
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\problem.py", line 767, in _setup_recording
    self._rec_mgr.startup(self, self.comm)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\recorders\recording_manager.py", line 75, in startup
    recorder.startup(recording_requester, comm)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\recorders\sqlite_recorder.py", line 332, in startup
    self._initialize_database(comm)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\recorders\sqlite_recorder.py", line 238, in _initialize_database
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE global_iterations(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
sqlite3.OperationalError: table global_iterations already exists
"""
```

Comment: (1) Probably the cause of the problem is not in the shown code. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: I've added the full traceback.

Comment: You have not posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is, you are missing important import statements and function definitions. It appears that you are getting this error from an installed package named `openmdao`, for which you have not shown the import statement and I have no idea what the `phase.interp` function/method is. But `openmdao` is trying to create a SQLite database that already exists.

Comment: seems like the problem is that whatever API you are using (openmdao) is internally using SQLITE to save some global information, this prevents any possible form of parallelism until you figure out how to make each process save its data to a different file/folder, changing the current directory in each child is the first thing i would try, but since there is no code in the question that can be run/tested, no answer can be provided.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added a simplified version of the code that should suffice as an MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dymos/OpenMDAO function `dymos.run_problem` has attributes `solution_record_file='dymos_solution.db'`, and `simulation_record_file='dymos_simulation.db'` which store the desired timeseries outputs from the optimization. These are called at later points to be stored in the excel file. As pointed out by Ahmed AEK, multiprocessing in this situation, creates a race condition where each "simulation" is trying to access/overwrite the same `'dymos_solution.db'` file. This was simply solved by getting each process to save a unique `'dymos_solution.db'` file by specifying `dm.run_problem(p, run_driver=True, simulate = True, solution_record_file='dymos_solution'+str(Counter)+'.db',simulation_record_file='dymos_simulation'+str(Counter)+'.db')`.